# How to fix the maxlistenersexceeded warning in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

On my studoes with NodeJS I've found an issue/warning the is getting me a bit worried because I would like to avoid memory leaks, but since this language is a bit new to me, I can't find which of my code is doing it.

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const assert = require('assert');
const fs = require("fs");

const conversor = require("./converterSiteEmObjeto");

// Connection URL
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';

// Database config
const client = new MongoClient(url, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });

async function salvarBanco(listaLinks) {
    try {
        await client.connect();

        console.log("Connected successfully to server");

        const db = client.db('consultadados');
        
        // Iterates through the list of links
        for (link of listaLinks) {
            // scrape data from link and return a JS object
            let resultado = await conversor(link);

            // insert object into DB and asserts
            let r = await db.collection('cnpjs').insertOne(resultado);
            assert.equal(1, r.insertedCount);
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err.stack);
    }

    client.close();
    console.log("Done...");
};

function converterSitemapEmListaLinks() {
    // Reads file containing links
    fs.readFile('links/sitemap.txt', 'utf8', function (err, contents) {
        //creates a array of links (100+ links)
        let listaLinks = contents.split("\n");

        //saves to database
        salvarBanco(listaLinks);
    });
}

converterSitemapEmListaLinks();
```

It runs just fine, but after a few dozen iteractions on listaLinks (list of links) I get the following message:
" MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 SIGHUP listeners added to [process]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit "

I know what it means, what I would like is to know how to fix it instead of simply setting the listeners to a higher max value.

Comment: Try to open the connection only once (call `client.connect()` only once).

Comment: Moving th client.connect outside the async function salvarBanco() ?

Comment: @PauloKünzel How did you solve the warning?

Comment: @Titus How to open connection only once? I mean, `client.connect()` is already called once i.e. outside the for loop.